# Jade bug loading order of scripts is messed up

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, pug, metronic

I am trying to use Metronic admin theme on my web pages and want to convert my templates to jade/pug. Unfortunately, I encountered a bug that I am not able to work around nicely. Whenever, Metronic loads a page, it loads the core scripts first and then depending on what else you have on the page it loads page specific plugins and scripts. In order to mimic this functionality I created a footer.pug file that contains the core plugins and **blocks** for page specific plugins and scripts:

```
    // BEGIN CORE PLUGINS
script(src='../assets/global/plugins/jquery.min.js', type='text/javascript')
script(src='../assets/global/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js', type='text/javascript')
script(src='../assets/global/plugins/js.cookie.min.js', type='text/javascript')
script(src='../assets/global/plugins/jquery-slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js', type='text/javascript')
script(src='../assets/global/plugins/jquery.blockui.min.js', type='text/javascript')
script(src='../assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-switch/js/bootstrap-switch.min.js', type='text/javascript')
// END CORE PLUGINS

// BEGIN PAGE LEVEL PLUGINS
block page_level_plugins
// END PAGE LEVEL PLUGINS

// BEGIN THEME GLOBAL SCRIPTS
script(src='../assets/global/scripts/app.min.js', type='text/javascript')
// END THEME GLOBAL SCRIPTS

// BEGIN PAGE LEVEL SCRIPTS
block page_level_scripts
// END PAGE LEVEL SCRIPTS

// BEGIN THEME LAYOUT SCRIPTS
script(src='../assets/layouts/layout/scripts/layout.min.js', type='text/javascript')
script(src='../assets/layouts/global/scripts/quick-sidebar.min.js', type='text/javascript')
script(src='../assets/layouts/global/scripts/quick-nav.min.js', type='text/javascript')
// END THEME LAYOUT SCRIPTS
```

This footer.pug file is included my simple layout.pug:

```
doctype html
html
  head
    if title
      title= title
    else
      title Template page
    include head
  body.page-header-fixed.page-sidebar-closed-hide-logo.page-content-white.page-md
    .page-wrapper
      include header
      .page-container
        .page-content-wrapper
          .page-content
            block content
  include footer
```

When I write my actual web page, I extend the layout.pug and add a block at the end with the name of **page_level_plugins**

```
extends partials/layout
block content
  if title
    h1= title
  ...

  block page_level_plugins
    script(src='../assets/global/plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js', type='text/javascript')
```

When I look in the browser Inspector, the correct html has been created, the scripts are in the correct order
[image: javascript files are in correct order]

However, when I look at my network tab, I can see that JQueryUI has been downloaded before JQuery:

[image: Scripts are loaded in the wrong order]

And I get an error in the console, that I am trying to load JQueryUI  before JQuery. And for some reason, I get the error twice:

[image: Console error]

Has anyone found a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is a work around. It's not really a solution for the bug: I used the **defer** attribute for the JQueryUI script library like this:

```
 block page_level_plugins
    script(defer src='../assets/global/plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js', type='text/javascript')
```